# Exsheets: Switching solution printing on/off multiple times

Tags: exsheets

I'm having some troubles with the (otherwise excellent) exsheets package. I want to switch between printing the solution to a question and not printing it multiple times in one document. I am trying to do this by using the command `\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=false}` (or `true`) before the appropriate block of questions/answers.

According to the documentation, that should result in the option `print` being "set for all following uses of the corresponding environment" (`solution` in this case). However, once I switch printing on, I cannot seem to switch it off again, even though the command `\PrintSolutionsTF` gives the correct value (true/false). Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? (I'd like to use this functionality as part of a more general document class, so I would like to avoid setting the print option individually for each solution).

Here's an MWE that shows what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
Let's switch solution printing on.
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=true}
\PrintSolutionsTF{print solutions=true}{print solutions=false}

\begin{question}
  First Question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Answer to first question
\end{solution}


Let's switch solution printing off.
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=false}
\PrintSolutionsTF{print solutions=true}{print solutions=false}
\begin{question}
  Second Question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Answer to second question

  \PrintSolutionsTF{print solutions=true}{print solutions=false}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

The output shows *"print solutions=true"*, the first solution renders correctly, then *"print solution=false"*, but in spite of this the second solution is also printed. The picture shows the output of my code.
[image]

Comment: I don't think you doing something wrong. This usage is imho not expected, the print=false doesn't reset all bools. Make a feature request.

Comment: There's something wrong… :( Can you [make a bug report](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues/new), please?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I filed a bug report as recommended. Please let me know if I can help in some way.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles upon this question: The issue has been resolved in the current release of exsheets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was a bug report (the bug is long fixed, an update will fix the problem)